Json Serializable Does not import required class
Is this a known limitation with inheritance using  https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable or am I doing something wrong ? I hope the solution is to not simply include the import manually in the correct file . Because this is minimum reproducible example. In large projects that change a lot, simply doing that manually is not that simple.
The crazy part is that this is a compile time error. Static analysis can't find this.
main.dart
import 'foo.dart';

void main() {
  final foo = Foo.fromJson({
    "id": "1",
    "baz": {"id": "2" },
  });
  print(foo.id);
}

foo.dart
import 'package:app_core/model/bar.dart';
import 'package:app_core/repository_helper/json_map.dart';
import 'package:app_core/utils/annotations/annotations.dart';

part 'foo.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Foo extends Bar {
  final String id;

  Foo({
    required this.id,
    required super.baz,
  });

  factory Foo.fromJson(JsonMap json) => _$FooFromJson(json);

  JsonMap toJson() => _$FooToJson(this);
}

bar.dart
import 'package:app_core/model/baz.dart';
import 'package:app_core/repository_helper/json_map.dart';
import 'package:app_core/utils/annotations/annotations.dart';

part 'bar.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Bar {
  final Baz baz;

  Bar({required this.baz});

  factory Bar.fromJson(JsonMap json) => _$BarFromJson(json);

  JsonMap toJson() => _$BarToJson(this);
}

baz.dart
import 'package:app_core/repository_helper/json_map.dart';
import 'package:app_core/utils/annotations/annotations.dart';

part 'baz.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Baz {
  final String id;

  Baz({required this.id});

  factory Baz.fromJson(JsonMap json) => _$BazFromJson(json);

  JsonMap toJson() => _$BazToJson(this);
}

Run build_runner then Launch dart run main.dart.
lib/model/foo.g.dart:11:12: Error: Undefined name 'Baz'.
      baz: Baz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['baz'] as Map)),
           ^^^

json_map.dart
typedef JsonMap =  Map<string, dynamic>;


This will not work unless JsonMap is just a typedef of Map<string, dynamic>. You should provide a JsonCoverter if it is a custom class

typedef JsonMap =  Map<string, dynamic>; to keep things short

But JsonMap has nothing to do with the question, it's just an alias of   Map<string, dynamic>;

Unfortunately there is no solution to your problem which does not involve manually importing those files.
JsonSerializable relies on including the generated {file_name}.g.dart as a part directive in the input file {file_name}.dart. Since Dart does not support transitive imports, each Dart file must explicitly import the libraries it directly uses.
The generated file foo.g.dart is part of foo.dart and therefore relies on its imports to work. foo.dart does not have access to Baz class unless it also directly imports the file containing Baz class.
I would be great that the builder would allow for using alternatively an "import" directive for the .g.dart instead of "part", and then import in the generated file the required imports... however it is not the case at the current date.
